# Closed curve line integral over conservative field not equal to $0$?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis, line-integrals

In the screenshot below, I am trying to evaluate two closed line integrals over the regions $C_1=x^2+y^2=1$ and $C_2=4x^2+9y^2=36$. In this specific case, however, the partials of the line integral are equal to each other ($P_y=Q_x$). Thus, since this is a conservative field over a closed path, the integrals should evaluate to 0 (which means they are equal).

The part I do not understand is part B, where we are asked to actually evaluate the two line integrals. Parametrizing the path $x^2+y^2 = 1$ and evaluating it yields $2\pi$ -- which I do not get. If the vector field is conservative, and the path is closed, how does the line integral evaluate to a non-zero value?

Thanks for all the help!

[image]

Comment: A huge number of related questions can be found with [Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24(%5Cfrac%20%7B-y%7D%7Bx%5E2%2By%5E2%7D%2C%5Cfrac%20x%7Bx%5E2%2By%5E2%7D)%24&p=1#). I left out a part of the vector field, because the radial part actually has a potential in the puncture plane.

Comment: Nominating [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1959775/11619) as one of the best. You are welcome to pick your favorite among those dupes.

Comment: [This](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/882793/11619) deals well with the potential. Observe that $$\frac1{x^2+y^2)(x,y)$$ has $\dfrac12\ln(x^2+y^2)$ as a potential, so your field needs to take that into account.

Comment: You can answer a) without computing the integrals, because Green's theorem does apply to the region bounded by $C_1$ and $C_2$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You’re making a common mistake: when the domain isn’t simply connected, being irrotational doesn’t always mean that the vector field is conservative. In this case, there’s a hole in the domain at the origin, so the integral along a closed path that surrounds this hole might not vanish.